# Python Igraph : Finding number of triangles for each vertex

Tags: python, igraph

How can I find the number of triangles for vertices in a graph ?

Let say I have a graph `g`. I can calculate the degree for each vertex using this command

```
g.vs.degree()
```

It will return a list of numbers. Is there any similar method to count the number of triangles that will return a list ?

Previously I can calculate using Gephi, but now I'm shifted to igraph.

---

**Update 1**

By using `cliques`, i will get something like this

```
import igraph as ig
g = ig.Graph.Famous('Krackhardt_Kite')
g.cliques(min=3,max=3)

[(0, 1, 3),
 (0, 2, 3),
 (0, 2, 5),
 (0, 3, 5),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (1, 3, 6),
 (1, 4, 6),
 (2, 3, 5),
 (3, 4, 6),
 (3, 5, 6),
 (5, 6, 7)]
```

So the number of triangles should be return like this (based on Gephi)

```
[4,4,3,8,3,5,5,1,0]
```

So does igraph provide these function to calculate the number of triangles ?

Comment: Also, there is available `triangles()` and `count_triangles()`. Tested on `R`. More at https://igraph.org/r/doc/count_triangles.html

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most efficient, but this will work:

```
def triangles(g):
    cliques = g.cliques(min=3, max=3)
    result = [0] * g.vcount()
    for i, j, k in cliques:
        result[i] += 1
        result[j] += 1
        result[k] += 1
    return result
```

Another variant which does not use `cliques()`:

```
from itertools import combinations

def triangles(g):
    result = [0] * g.vcount()
    adjlist = [set(neis) for neis in g.get_adjlist()]
    for vertex, neis in enumerate(adjlist):
        for nei1, nei2 in combinations(neis, 2):
            if nei1 in adjlist[nei2]:
                result[vertex] += 1
    return result
```

I haven't done any benchmarks so this one might be faster or slower than the previous one - I have no idea.

Comment: yea i saw this way before, a post by Csardi.. but yes not that efficient bcos need to go to cliques function first.. but if there's no other way, i guess need to use this way.. it way took lot of time for a big network

Comment: I have added another variant that does not rely on `cliques()`.